# $\eta(1) = \ln(2)$ proof using Abel's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, riemann-zeta

Hi I was just wondering how does one justify $\eta(1) = \ln(2)$. Looking at the power series for $\ln(1+x)$ we have

\begin{equation}
\ln(1+x)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n}}{n}
\end{equation}

This expansion is only valid for $|x| <1$. Can we use Abels theorem here? How would I go about this?

Comment: Well, what does Abel's theorem say about this?

Comment: $\log(1+x)$ is a continuous function in a neighbourhood of $x=1$, hence $\eta(1)=\log(2)$ by Abel's lemma.

Comment: Due to the functions convergence, we can say that the $\lim _ {x \rightarrow 1^{-}} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n}}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}?$

Comment: yes u can use abels theorem.

Answer (score 3):

By the alternating series test, we can see that the sum converges and

$$\frac12<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n<1$$

By Abel's theorem,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n=\lim_{x\to1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}n=\lim_{x\to1^-}\ln(1+x)=\ln(2)$$